# Searching dictionary in array using predicate

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, nsdictionary, predicate

I have an array of dictionaries and I want to find the dictionary with desired value for key "guid".
Can not get it with this code:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"guid = %@", key];
NSArray *filteredContacts = [selectedValue filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Comment: Please try to log the array for more comprehension

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Name CONTAINS[cd] %@",searchBar.text];

filterdArray = [[hospitalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];
```

Where `Name` is the key contained in the dictionary under the array.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forgot "=" sign.

```
 NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"guid == %@", key];
 NSArray *filteredContacts = [selectedValue filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

Comment: I have nil in after filteredArrayUsingPredicate.

Comment: I have array of dictionaries and searching for dictionary for it value

Comment: Please try NSLog(%@, selectedValue); and copy the content on your post

Answer (score 0):

The operator condition has been forgotten ;)

You need to add a double "=" like this :

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"guid == %@", key];
NSArray *filteredContacts = [selectedValue filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
```

I hope this can help you !

Comment: Oops, same answer as @PratikMistry, sorry !

Comment: yep, I answer to him, please look

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(guid CONTAINS[c] %@)",key];
NSArray *array = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:sampleArray] filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
```

in above code "fromDate" is key of dictionary.

i hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to initiate the NSPredicate as:

```
NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"guid = '%@'", key]];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSArray *filtered = [array_with_dict filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(guid == %@)", @"desired value"]];
```